# What is "Segmentation Fault (core dumped)" and why is it being returned in my output?

Tags: c, fgets, getchar, strlen

I am trying to replace the loop containing repeated getchar calls with a single call to fgets

When I try to type an input I get Segmentation Fault (core dumped) and I don't know what that is or why I get it.

**Starter Code**

```
/* Example: analysis of text */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 1000 /* The maximum number of characters in a line of input */

main()
{
  char text[MAX], c;
  int i;
  int lowercase, uppercase, digits, other;
  int length;

  puts("Type some text (then ENTER):");

  /* Save typed characters in text[]: */
  // In ex1.c, please implement the following loop with fgets() and use strlen() to compute the length of the string
  //
  for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
  {
    text[i] = getchar();
    if (text[i] == '\n')
      break;
  }
  length = i;

  /* Analyse contents of text[]: */

  for (i = lowercase = uppercase = digits = other = 0; i < MAX; i++)
  {
    c = text[i];
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
      lowercase++;
    else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
      uppercase++;
    else if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
      digits++;
    else
    {
      if (c == '\n')
        break;
      other++;
    }
  }

  puts("\nYou typed:");
  printf("A string with %d characters\n", length);
  printf("\t%d lower case letters\n", lowercase);
  printf("\t%d upper case letters\n", uppercase);
  printf("\t%d digits\n", digits);
  printf("\t%d others\n", other);
}
```

**Starter Code Test**

```
Type some text (then ENTER):
asd213qaIW

You typed:
A string with 10 characters
    5 lower case letters
    2 upper case letters
    3 digits
    0 others
```

**My Code**

```
/* Example:  analysis of text */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 1000 /* The maximum number of characters in a line of input */

main()
{
  char text[MAX], c;
  int i;
  int lowercase, uppercase, digits, other;
  int length;

  puts("Type some text (then ENTER):");

  /* Save typed characters in text[]: */
  // In ex1.c, please implement the following loop with fgets() and use strlen() to compute the length of the string
  //
  c = fgets(text, MAX, stdin);
  length = strlen(c);

  /* Analyse contents of text[]: */

  for (i = lowercase = uppercase = digits = other = 0; i < MAX; i++)
  {
    c = text[i];
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
      lowercase++;
    else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
      uppercase++;
    else if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
      digits++;
    else
    {
      if (c == '\n')
        break;
      other++;
    }
  }

  puts("\nYou typed:");
  printf("A string with %d characters\n", length);
  printf("\t%d lower case letters\n", lowercase);
  printf("\t%d upper case letters\n", uppercase);
  printf("\t%d digits\n", digits);
  printf("\t%d others\n", other);
}
```

**My Code Test**

```
Type some text (then ENTER):
asd213qaIW  
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.
I'm also very new to C so if you could explain as simply as possible.

**Changing** `length = strlen(c);` **to** `length = strlen(text);` **fixed it.  Thank you!**

Comment: Questions should be self-contained (see [mcve]). Don't post links to code and don't post images of code

Comment: It means your program is trying to read or write a memory location that doesn't exist.

Comment: Your code shouldn't even compile `char` and `char*` are two very different types. Turn on all compiler warnings and never ever ignore them

Comment: `text` will be terminated by `\0` not `\n`;

Comment: @Stavr00 `fgets()` reads a line and leaves the newline in it, unless the line is longer than `MAX`

Comment: @UnholySheep Where do you see `char*` in the code, or where is it missing?

Comment: @Barmar in the "my code" part, OP is assigning the result of `fgets` to a `char c` variable. They are also calling `strlen(c);` on the same `char`

Comment: `length = strlen(c);` should be `length = strlen(text);`

Comment: You should assign the return value of `fgets()` to a pointer variable, then check the value to see if it's `NULL`, which means it got an error or EOF.

Comment: It’s an error all experienced C programmers become familiar with. It’s usually caused by dereferencing a pointer that was in some way invalid: a null pointer, an uninitialized pointer, a pointer that’s already been freed, an out-of-bounds array access, some garbage cast to a pointer type by mistake, etc.

Comment: Step one in debugging this error is to find what input reproduces the crash, compile with degugging symbols and run the program in a debugger. That will tell you, at least, which line of code crashed the program and usually which pointer was invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Your error, or at least one of them, appears to be in the following lines:

```
char text[MAX], c;
// ...

c = fgets(text, MAX, stdin);
length = strlen(c);
```

The return value of `fgets` is a **pointer to** `char`, but you’re storing it in a `char` and then try to pass the `char` value to a function that expects a **pointer to** `char`.  Since `char` is only 8 bits wide (on any machine you’d be compiling on) and a pointer needs 32 or 64 bits, most of the bits get lost and the result is an invalid pointer.  This will—if you’re lucky—crash the program with a segmentation fault.

This code really should not have compiled at all.  If you didn’t get at least a warning that `c` cannot hold a **pointer to** `char`, you need to turn on more warning flags.  (On `gcc` or `clang`, I usually compile with `-std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wconversion`.)  Then, at least while you’re learning the language, treat any warning you get as a bug in your program. Better yet, add `-Werror` (or the equivalent for your compiler) to make the compiler treat them that way.

The simplest fix is to eliminate `c` and write instead

```
fgets( text, MAX, stdin );
length = strlen(text);
```